# Hammer.js how to recognize gesture below end of document

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js to switch tabs via swipe left/right gestures in a single page web app. Each tab is represented by a `<div>`, they are switched like this:

```
this.content.style.display = on ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Some tabs have very little content, and Hammer.js does not recognize gestures below the end of the document. But I'd like Hammer to be sensitive in the entire browser window. How can I achieve it?

Currently I create the Hammer instance like this:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(document.body);
hammer.on('swipeleft swiperight press', function(ev) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note to editors: adding `javascript` tag did the trick with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not force Hammer to work outside the `document.body`. But I could force the `document.body` to fill the entire window. Via CSS:

```css
body { height: 100% }
```